# Likelihood contribution of censored data - why conditional?

Tags: survival, likelihood, truncation

Let $x_i$ be a sample of survival time from right-truncated data with right-truncation time $Y_R$. I would like to find the likelihood contribution from the sample.

I thought I have to find the probability $P(\textrm{The data was not truncated and } X=x_i)$ or $P(X<Y_R,X=x_i)$ where $X$ is survival time.

However, my textbook says it would be $f(x)/[1-S(Y_R)]$ where $f$ is pdf/pmf and $S(t)$ is the survival function. I think this is equivalent to $P(X=x_i|X<Y_R)$, which is different from my guess.

I do not understand why it has to be conditional probability instead of an intersection.

Comment: But you *know* because of the design that if $x_i$ is any value other than $Y_R$, then the case is not truncated.

Comment: @AdamO I am not sure I understand. Do you mean that the event $\{X\neq Y_R\}$ is equal to the event $\{\textrm{the data was not truncated}\}$?

Comment: Well, maybe. Since you omit any subscript $i$, I assume $Y_R$ is a constant, like a 5-year timepoint after which subjects unenroll from study. I am assuming further that they are not otherwise censored randomly as well. So in that case, yes. $X \ne Y_R$ or more specifically $X < Y_R$ implies the event was not truncated.

Comment: It might help to know the textbook. You and I are saying "right truncation" when the formula you provide above are actually consistent with *left* truncation, at least according to Hosmer, Lemeshow, May - the book I wrote survival from like a decade ago.

Comment: @AdamO my textbook is Klein, Melvin "SURVIVAL ANALYSIS Techniques for Censored and Truncated Data".

Comment: @AdamO Maybe I don't understand conditional probability. Is it conditional because we had the information that any data we observe would not be truncated?